# Another simple query with a SQL Statement (from someone just learning SQL)

Tags: sql

Really sorry to ask all you experts what I'm doing wrong with this SQL Statement.

All I'm trying to do is list the Sales Person from the SalesExec Table and show the number of new Cars from the New Table and the number of Used Cars from the Used Table that that Salesman has sold.

```
SELECT SALESEXEC.SALESEXECNAME 
COUNT(NewSALES.CHASSIS) AS newCOUNT
COUNT(UsedSales.CHASSIS) AS usedCOUNT
FROM SALESEXEC.csv SALESEXEC, NewSALES.csv NewSALES, UsedSALES.csv UsedSALES
WHERE SALESEXEC.ID = NewSALES.SALESEXECID And SALESEXEC.ID = UsedSALES.SALESEXECID
GROUP BY SALESEXEC.SALESEXECNAME
```

This statement seems to return the same number for both the newCOUNT and usedCOUNT and I don't even know where that number has come from?

Again, I really appreciate any help on this. THanks in advance

Steve

Comment: This shouldn't be difficult, but you will have to post all your schema

Comment: The problem is in a way you're joining tables - basically this query returns all posible combinations of NewSALES.CHASSIS and UsedSales.CHASSIS for given SALESEXECNAME, and this is the number you are getting. Consider dividing this query into two different - one for each table, or, if CHASSIS fields is unique, add DISTINCT in COUNT clause, for example: `COUNT(DISTINCT NewSALES.CHASSIS)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SALESEXEC.SALESEXECNAME, newCOUNT, usedCOUNT
FROM SALESEXEC.csv SALESEXEC
JOIN (
    SELECT SALESEXECID, COUNT(CHASSIS) AS newCOUNT
    FROM NewSALES.csv
    GROUP BY SALESEXECID
) NewSALES ON SALESEXEC.ID = NewSALES.SALESEXECID
JOIN (
    SELECT SALESEXECID, COUNT(CHASSIS) AS usedCOUNT
    FROM UsedSALES.csv 
    GROUP BY SALESEXECID
) UsedSALES ON SALESEXEC.ID = UsedSALES.SALESEXECID
```